# Is it possible to read the thread environment block of another process?

Tags: c++, windows, memory

Are there any ways people are aware of for reading the TEB of another process?

The TEB structure can be seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/ns-winternl-_teb however I have not been able to find any methods or libraries for accessing the TEB.

Comment: this is very easy. you need query `NtQueryInformationThread` with `ThreadBasicInformation`. and inside `THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION` exist `TebBaseAddress`. so if you know thread id you can do this. another question - for what ?

Comment: Do you know of any examples online for this?

Comment: for what ? i can write this yourself in 5 min. what you have as input ? thread id ? and what is your final target ?

Comment: Thread ID or Thread handle as input. Final goal being a populated TEB structure.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Ghcyu65H - use